# Prevent primefaces datatable select new row when validation fails

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a master detail ui showing some items in a dataTable. If a item is selected the details are shown in a form.
If there is invalid data in the form I want to prevent that the user is able to select a new item from the dataTable. A validation already error is shown on the details side and the form is not updated when a validation error is existing (seems to be a bulit-in behaviour).
Unfortunately I wasn't able to prevent that the user can select another row in the dataTable. I tried:

```
<p:dataTable ...>               
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="someId" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="someId" oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) return false;" process=":detialsFormId" />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

But this doesn't work. As I know only in `oncomplete` there is the `args` variable available. I think in both `rowSelect` and `rowUnselect` it is too late.
Maybe there is another approach? Thought about a remote command which sets the t-1 selection when validation failed. But maybe there's another fancier solution?

Regards
Oliver

Comment: You could put the form in a dialog and make it modal. That is one of the usual ways to prevent other actions

Comment: The master detail is already inside a dialog. The master is on the left in a p:layout and the detail in another layout on the right. The user must be able to switch fast through the items also.

Comment: then try a block-ui thing that you activate if there is a validation error in the form. And remove again if it is completed without validation

Comment: I already thought about this. But I have to suppress the selection in the datatable anyway. If the user selects an item which has a detail fields which is required and empty and the user selects immediately another item from the datatable, then I have the situation to switch back to the preselected item. Maybe I should do all validation stuff at the end when the save button is clicked and not with the blur event. But this could generate lots of validation messages (same as datatable items count).

Comment: The latter you suggest sounds wrong. Let me think about a different solution

Comment: I will add a save button on the details side. This save button will validate and submit the form. The blur event will be removed. The user has to save each edited item explicitly and if he changes to another item without saving the data is lost. But I think this easier to implement.